# Fortran Silverfrost compiler creates .exes that can't be deleted

Tags: windows, fortran, windows-10, exe, silverfrost-fortran

I'm on Windows 10 on a new computer, not from work. Every now and then, seemingly at random, my Silverfrost compiler (up to date as of 28th July 2017) will create a .exe file when I compile that requests admin rights to delete, move, or modify. The thing is, I am the administrator, and the file doesn't care.

I try deleting it as an administrator, I try running the command line as an administrator and deleting it, I try modifying the permissions of the folder its in to recursively give me rights, nothing works. The only way I can delete it is if I boot my PC from a linux USB.

Comment: Isn't the program still running? I would contact the tech support of your compiler vendor.

Comment: I've restarted my computer and still it remains undeletable.

Comment: My guess is that it's your antivirus program that is holding the file open. AV programs often create problems with compilers as they treat newly-created EXEs as suspicious. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle for a handy tool to check.